# Port GTK Program to Windows Without X Server

Tags: windows, winapi, gtk, porting, xserver

How would one go about porting a GTK program to Windows that's meant specifically for Linux desktop environments, such as xfce4-terminal ?

[image: showcase]

It would be ideal to port the program without the need of a secondary application such as the X Server running in the background.

Is there any replacement for the X Server bindings that these programs use, and somehow have the ability to draw the application by embedding the X Server within the application itself?